# Conditional Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to assign different routes depending on the internal setting. A simple `if` won't work here as `routes.rb` is only evaluated on change/start. I want to redirect all requests to a maintenance page if the maintenance is in progress without changing the current URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a before filter in the ApplicationController that renders a maintenance template. It should look something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :show_maintenance_page

  private

  def show_maintenance_page
    render 'common/maintenance' if maintenance?  # you have to define maintenance?
  end
end
```

Comment: I assume the return value makes it somehow not proceed any further. Otherwise thanks :)

Comment: Actually when a before filter renders a template or redirects it halts the request.

Answer (score 3):

You could set an action in the ApplicationController as a `before_filter` to check an environment variable and, if that is set, `render` a maintenance template.  This shouldn't affect the current URL.